# mysqldb interfaceError

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a very weird problem with mysqldb (mysql module for python).

I have a file with queries for inserting records in tables. If I call the functions from the file, it works just fine; but when trying to call one of the functions from another file it throws me a

> _mysql_exception.InterfaceError: (0, '')

I really don't get what I'm doing wrong here..

I call the function from `buildDB.py` :

```
import create

create.newFormat("HD", 0,0,0)
```

The function newFormat(..) is in create.py (imported) :

```
from Database import Database

db = Database()

def newFormat(name, width=0, height=0, fps=0):
    format_query = "INSERT INTO Format (form_name, form_width, form_height, form_fps)  VALUES ('"+name+"',"+str(width)+","+str(height)+","+str(fps)+");"
    db.execute(format_query)
```

And the class Database is the following :

import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb.constants import FIELD_TYPE

```
class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        server = "localhost"
        login = "seq"
        password = "seqmanager"
        database = "Sequence"
        my_conv = { FIELD_TYPE.LONG: int }

        self.conn = MySQLdb.connection(host=server, user=login, passwd=password, db=database, conv=my_conv)
        # self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()

    def execute(self, query):
        self.conn.query(query)
```

(I put only relevant code)

Traceback :

```
Z:\sequenceManager\mysql>python buildDB.py
D:\ProgramFiles\Python26\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py:34: DeprecationWa
rning: the sets module is deprecated
  from sets import ImmutableSet
INSERT INTO Format (form_name, form_width, form_height, form_fps) VALUES ('HD',0
,0,0);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "buildDB.py", line 182, in <module>
    create.newFormat("HD")
  File "Z:\sequenceManager\mysql\create.py", line 52, in newFormat
    db.execute(format_query)
  File "Z:\sequenceManager\mysql\Database.py", line 19, in execute
    self.conn.query(query)
_mysql_exceptions.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

The warning has never been a problem before so I don't think it's related.

Comment: Can you provide the code where the query gets called?

Comment: Traceback added, it doesn't say much more ..

Answer (score 20):

I got this error when I was trying to use a closed connection.

Comment: This includes if the connection was internally closed, not just if you called `close()` on the connection

Answer (score 3):

Problem resolved.. I was initializing the database twice.. Sorry if you lost your time reading this !

Comment: Are you still using the *query* method? I think it doesn't allow for param substition. It's a big security risk, due to the possibility of SQL injection attacks. If there is any user input it should always be escaped first by the db module.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your setup to work. I gives me the same error all the time. However the way you connect to and make queries to the db with the *query* seems to be  ["non-standard"](http://www.mikusa.com/python-mysql-docs/docs/MySQLdb.connections.html#Connection-query).
I had better luck with this setup:

```
conn = MySQLdb.Connection(user="user", passwd="******", 
                          db="somedb", host="localhost")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into Format values (%s,%s,%s,%s);", ("hd",0,0,0))
```

This way you can take advantage of the db modules input escaping which is a must to mitigate sql injection attacks.

Comment: I tried to use a cursor, but it gives me an error "Attribute Error: cursor" And I don't understand why. That's why I don't use it.. Maybe you could help me with that ?

Comment: Yeah, the way you use the MySQLdb package is 'non-standard' (says the documentation). When you use MySQLdb.Connection (with a capital C), you get a connection object that has a __cursor__ method.