# MySQL Python update rows

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to update the data in a row of MySQL which this line of code is throwing this error.

```
for k in range(city_count):
    cur.execute("UPDATE hqstock SET citylastprice = '%s' WHERE id = '%s'"%(CITYPRICE[k],   tID[k]))
```

The error that was returned:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

This is my table structure.

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                 |int(11) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| barcode            | char(15)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| citycurstock       | smallint(6)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| citylastprice      | demical(4,2)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| city               | varchar(60)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Anybody knows what is wrong with my query statement? or why doesn't this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqldb interfaceError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704590/mysqldb-interfaceerror) and [InterfaceError (0, '')](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6650940)

Comment: Note: don't use string interpolation; use SQL parameters instead: `cur.execute("UPDATE hqstock SET citylastprice = %s WHERE id = %s", (CITYPRICE[k], tID[k]))`; this leaves quoting to the database adapter (safer and more convenient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
for k in range(city_count):
    cur.execute("UPDATE hqstock SET citylastprice = '%s' WHERE id = '%s'"% (CITYPRICE[k],   tID[k]))
    cur.commit()
```

Comment: works like a charm. This helps the second problem i encountered. thank you